# How to prevent iterator getting exhausted?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I create two lists and zip them

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[7,8,9]
z=zip(a,b)
```

Then I typecast z into two lists

```
l1=list(z)
l2=list(z)
```

Then the contents of l1 turn out to be fine [(1,7),(2,8),(3,9)], but the contents of l2 is just [].

I guess this is the general behavior of python with regards to iterables. But as a novice programmer migrating from the C family, this doesn't make sense to me. Why does it behave in such a way? And is there a way to get past this problem?

I mean, yeah in this particular example, I can just copy l1 into l2, but in general is there a way to 'reset' whatever Python uses to iterate 'z' after I iterate it once?

Comment: It's behaviour of *generators*, not all iterables. Lists, for example, are iterables, and you can call `list(a)` and get copies of `a` as much as you want.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's no way to "reset" a generator. However, you *can* use `itertools.tee` to "copy" an iterator.

```
>>> z = zip(a, b)
>>> zip1, zip2 = itertools.tee(z)
>>> list(zip1)
[(1, 7), (2, 8), (3, 9)]
>>> list(zip2)
[(1, 7), (2, 8), (3, 9)]
```

This involves caching values, so it only makes sense if you're iterating through both iterables at about the same rate. (In other words, don't use it the way I have here!)

Another approach is to pass around the generator function, and call it whenever you want to iterate it.

```
def gen(x):
    for i in range(x):
        yield i ** 2

def make_two_lists(gen):
    return list(gen()), list(gen())
```

But now you have to bind the arguments to the generator function when you pass it. You can use `lambda` for that, but a lot of people find `lambda` ugly. (Not me though! YMMV.)

```
>>> make_two_lists(lambda: gen(10))
([0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81], [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81])
```

I hope it goes without saying that under most circumstances, it's better just to make a list and copy it.

Also, as a more general way of explaining this behavior, consider this. The point of a generator is to produce a series of values, while maintaining some state between iterations.  Now, at times, instead of simply iterating over a generator, you might want to do something like this:

```
z = zip(a, b)
while some_condition():
    fst = next(z, None)
    snd = next(z, None)
    do_some_things(fst, snd)
    if fst is None and snd is None:
        do_some_other_things()
```

Let's say this loop *may* or *may not* exhaust `z`. Now we have a generator in an indeterminate state! So it's important, at this point, that the behavior of a generator is restrained in a well-defined way. Although we don't know where the generator is in its output, we know that a) all subsequent accesses will produce *later* values in the series, and b) once it's "empty", we've gotten all the items in the series exactly once. The more ability we have to manipulate the state of `z`, the harder it is to reason about it, so it's best that we avoid situations that break those two promises.

Of course, as Joel Cornett points out below, it *is* possible to write a generator that accepts messages via the `send` method; and it would be possible to write a generator that could be reset using `send`. But note that in that case, *all we can do is send a message*. We can't directly manipulate the generator's state, and so all changes to the state of the generator are well-defined (by the generator itself -- assuming it was written correctly!). `send` is really for implementing [coroutines](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/), so I wouldn't use it for this purpose. Everyday generators almost never do anything with values sent to them -- I think for the very reasons I give above.

Comment: There's also the `send()` feature.

Comment: This works, but is complex and overkill, IMO. The "Don't use it like I do" is a hint of that as well. :-)

Comment: @LennartRegebro, well, I think `tee` exists for a good reason, and it's the closest thing in the standard libs that I can think of to the functionality the OP has requested. I assume that the OP already knows it's possible to copy the list!

Answer (score 4):

If you need two copies of the list, which you do if you need to modify them, then I suggest you make the list once, and then copy it:

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[7,8,9]
l1 = list(zip(a,b))
l2 = l1[:]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just create a list out of your iterator using `list()` once, and use it afterwards.

It just happens that `zip` returns a **generator**, which is an **iterator** that you can only iterate once.

You can iterate a list as many times as you want.

Comment: It's not really "casting", but this is usually the best approach. Also, you've correctly identified that 'iterator' is a super-category including generators and sequences, so this gets my vote for the best answer.

Comment: 10+ years later: on the other hand, the iterator created by `zip` isn't actually a generator (at least nowadays), but an instance of a class that implements the iterator protocol.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to "reset them".

Generators generate their output *once*, one by one, on demand, and then are done when the output is exhausted.

Think of them like reading a file, once you are through, you'll have to restart if you want to have another go at the data.

If you need to keep the generator's output around, then consider storing it, for instance, in a list, and subsequently re-use it as often as you need. (Somewhat similar to the decisions that guided the use of `xrange()`, a generator vs `range()` which created a whole list of items in memory in v2)

Updated: corrected terminology, temporary brain-outage ...

Comment: What you describe is basically done by `itertools.tee()`, as described in senderle's answer. +1 from me, though, as your discussion is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another explanation.  As a programmer, you probably understand the difference between classes vs. instances (i.e. objects).  The `zip()` is said to be a *built-in function* (in the official doc).  Actually, it is a *built-in **generator** function*.  It means it is rather the class.  You can even try in the interactive mode:

```
>>> zip
<class 'zip'>
```

The classes are types.  Because of that also the following should be clear:

```
>>> type(zip)
<class 'type'>
```

Your `z` is the instance of the class, and you can think about calling the `zip()` as about calling the class constructor:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [7, 8, 9]
>>> z = zip(a, b)
>>> z
<zip object at 0x0000000002342AC8>
>>> type(z)
<class 'zip'>
```

The `z` is an iterator (object) that keeps inside the iterators for the `a` and `b`.  Because of its generic implementation, the `z` (or the `zip` class) has no mean to reset the iterators through the `a` or `b` or whatever sequences.  Because of that there is no way to reset the `z`.  The cleanest way to solve your concrete problem is to copy the list (as you mentioned in the question and [Lennart Regebro suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10868567/1346705)).  Another understandable way is to use the `zip(a, b)` twice, thus constructing the two `z`-like iterators that behaves from the start the same way:

```
>>> lst1 = list(zip(a, b))
>>> lst2 = list(zip(a, b))
```

However, this cannot be used generally *with the identical result*.  Think about `a` or `b` being unique sequences generated based on some current conditions (say temperatures read from several thermometers).